# Escape Characters When Using Clip in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

The command that works on the command line is `for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %A in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com  2^>NUL^|find "Address:"') Do (echo %B)`

In a batch that becomes `for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com  2^>NUL^|find "Address:"') Do (echo %%B)` which works

But to copy to clip board I need to do more with the escape character in the `2^>NUL^|`. In batch the closest I've got it `echo.for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com  2^^^>NUL^^^|find "Address:"') Do (echo %%B)|clip`.

The output of which is `for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %A in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com  2>NUL|find "Address:"') Do (echo %B)` which fails as `2>nul|` is not escaped properly.

I tried adding a forth or even a fifth caret to `2>NUL|` to try clip the output as `2^>nul^|` but I can't figure it out.  Is it possible?

Comment: `2^^^^^^^>NUL^^^^^^^|`?

Comment: I should have just kept going with adding carets.  Seven done the trick.  This should be the accepted answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command line is parsed several times, so you must use enough escaping in order to hide special characters from all of them:

```cmd
echo for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com  2^^^^^^^> nul ^^^^^^^| find "Address:"'^) Do (echo(%%B^) | clip
```

At first the whole command line is parsed, which results in the following line:

> ```cmd
> echo for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com  2^^^> nul ^^^| find "Address:"') Do (echo(%%B) | clip
> ```

Next each side of the pipe (`|`) is parsed again, so the left side results in this line:

> ```cmd
> echo for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%A in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com  2^> nul ^| find "Address:"') Do (echo(%%B)
> ```

As you can see I also escaped the closing parentheses, so the code may also even be used within a parenthesised block of code.